# How to get a List object in a @ModelAttribute in the controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following code.

It retrieves listPlaces from the db and binds to the view.

That works fine.

Then I want to update the data on the view, click save and submit that info back to the controller for the controller to update the db with the change.

But when I click save, the code is not entering into the savePlaces method.

Instead it is throwing this error:

`No primary or default constructor found for interface java.util.List`

What I need to change to retrieve the List object in the savePlaces method?

Entity class

```
@Entity
public class Place implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idPlace;   

    @Column(length=50)
    private String place;

    public Long getIdPlace() {
        return idPlace;
    }

    public void setIdPlace(Long idPlace) {
        this.idPlace = idPlace;
    }

    public String getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(String place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

}
```

Controller GET method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/myplaces")
public ModelAndView initPlaces() {

    List<Place> listPlaces = placesRepository.getPlaces();

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
    modelAndView.addObject("listPlaces", listPlaces);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

View

```
<form action="/myplaces" method="post">
<th:block th:each="place, itemStat : *{listPlaces}">                    
  <input type="text" th:value="*{listPlaces[__${itemStat.index}__].place}" />
</th:block>
<input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Save"/>
```

Controller save method executed on btnSave click

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myplaces", params = "btnSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView savePlaces(@ModelAttribute List<Place> listPlaces) {

    //update db code here

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/myplaces.html");
    modelAndView.addObject("listPlaces", listPlaces);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: show your class `Place`

Comment: @manikant gautam Done. Just added the entity class to the question.

Comment: The error you posted is referring to `java.util.List` but there isn't any `List` in your pojo ? what is `placesRepository.getPlaces()` in ur `Repo` ?

Comment: You cannot use a `List` directly as a model object. You would need a wrapper object holding the list.

Comment: @manikant gautam Correct, there isn't. The list is in the controller GET method which passes it to the view.

Comment: @M. Deinum Yes, with a wrapper object I could get it to work. But wanted to have a simpler code without the need to have a wrapper object.